# How to compile, view or preview using markdown-mode

Tags: markdown-mode

I am using Emacs 25.1 on a Mac.
When I try to `view`, `preview` or `live export` a simple markdown file using markdown-mode in Emacs I obtain the following error: `/bin/bash: markdown: command not found`(in my browser or in a `eww` buffer).

Is it possible a result of a conflict between markdown-mode and pandoc-mode? What can I do to be able to view/preview markdown files using markdown-mode?

Comment: It seems that you don't have any executable called `markdown` in your PATH. Installing http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/ (preferably from some package manager like homebrew) should fix it.

Comment: Yes you're right. It works now. You can change your comment into an answer if you want a vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my comment fixed the problem, I'm posting it as an answer here.

It seems that you don't have any executable called markdown in your PATH. Installing daringfireball.net/projects/markdown (preferably from some package manager like homebrew) should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Installing `markdown` with `brew` didn't solve it for me. I had to add the following command to my **Emacs config** file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(markdown-command "/usr/local/bin/markdown"))
```

Also, later on I changed:

```
"/usr/local/bin/markdown"
```

to:

```
"/usr/local/bin/pandoc"
```

Because for some reason the preview and exported files were looking nicer (maybe it's just me), I would suggest giving it a try.